# Python libraries load very slowly in Azure Databricks cluster

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I have a very small Azure Databricks cluster with 12 libraries being loaded.  Ex:

```
altair==5.1.2
azure.storage.blob==12.17.0
gensim==4.3.0
```

... etc.

The cluster load time is pretty high (about 6 minutes), almost like it's installing the libraries on every start.  Maybe that's exactly what it's doing.  Is there a way to speed this along?

Answer (score 0):

To speed up the load time, you can use Databricks Runtime for Machine Learning (Databricks Runtime ML) or Databricks Runtime for Genomics (Databricks Runtime Genomics)

Some of Databricks Runtime for Machine Learning, you can use the following libraries:

- **TensorFlow** ,**Keras** ,**PyTorch** ,**XGBoost** **LightGBM** ,**Scikit-learn** ,**Pandas** ,**NumPy** **Matplotlib** ,**Seaborn** ,**Plotly** ,**Bokeh**, **Altair** **H2O.ai** ,**MLflow**

I have created a cluster with Databricks Runtime Version 12.2 **LTS ML (includes Apache Spark 3.3.2, GPU, Scala 2.12)**

[image]

You can also run the below commands I have tried installing these libraries which took less than a minute for me.

```
%pip install altair==5.1.2
%pip install azure.storage.blob==12.17.0
%pip install gensim==4.3.0
```